# При выводе CListView не работает limit

Tags: php, yii

Всем доброго дня.
Есть код в контроллере вывода Новостей:

```
        $newsCriteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $newsCriteria->order = '`created` DESC, `id` DESC';
        $newsCriteria->limit = 2;
        $news = new CActiveDataProvider('News', array(
            'criteria' => $newsCriteria,
        ));
```

Но при выводе на странице через CListView выводятся все элементы, т. е. не работает limit. В чем может быть проблема?

Код CListView:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$news,
    'itemView'=>'_news-prev',
    'template'=>"{items}",
)); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуй вот так

```
$newsCriteria = new CDbCriteria();
 $newsCriteria->order = '`created` DESC, `id` DESC';
 $news = new CActiveDataProvider('News', array(
            'criteria' => $newsCriteria,
            'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>2),
        ));
```

нашел вот это, походу про твой случай

If you are trying to limit the dataProvider results with your criteria, make sure to set the pagination to false.

for example

```
  $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('xxxxxx',array(
                    'criteria'=>array(                          
                      'condition'=>'yyyyy IS NULL',
                      'order'=>'id DESC',                          
                      'limit'=>5,
                    ),
```

You will have to use to set pagination to false to set the limit to 5, if not it won't work.

```
$dataProvider->setPagination(false);
```

Comment: Так, конечно, сработает, и даже как временное решение подойдет. Но все равно не понятно, почему не работает limit? Если я, например, захочу вывести первые 100 записей из 1000 с разбиением по 20 на страницу, то тут уже такой подход не прокатит, к сожалению

Comment: хм... Если я, например, захочу вывести первые 100 записей из 1000 с разбиением по 20 на страницу - у тебя это не получится использованием Limit и пагинации. Так это по сути одно и тоже - пагинация и использует конструкцию limit. Выход из твоей ситуации вижу только созданием условия выборки (конструкция where) из 1000 записей 100

Comment: мда.. здравая мысль. спасибо большое)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $newsCriteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $newsCriteria->order = '`created` DESC, `id` DESC';
        $newsCriteria->limit = 2;
$news = News::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

А вот при такой запись что тебе выведет? И вопрос зачем ты 2 раза сортируешь

```
$newsCriteria->order = '`created` DESC, `id` DESC'; // сначала создание потом по ID бредово как-то.
```

Comment: Падает с "PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getData() on a non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/yii/zii/widgets/CBaseListView.php on line 108"
А по поводу двойной сортировки - чтобы для совпадающих дат производилась сортировка по id.